# I want to drop_duplicates from TextFileReader and save what remains into separate files

Tags: python, pandas

So, I'm iterating over chunks in huge pandas' TextFileReader object and for each chunk I do drop_duplicates, then to_csv. Unfortunately, when I tried save everything in one file, it crashed after the file reached 4GB. I assumed I have to create couple of smaller csv's, that won't exceed 4GB size.

Now I'm testing my code on smaller file (300 lines) and smaller chunks, but the problem is that it either puts one chunk per file, if

```
if int(os.stat(ostatni_plik).st_size) < 'approx. size of a chunk':
```

Or it returns one empty file only, if

```
if int(os.stat(ostatni_plik).st_size) < 'much bigger or much smaller than a chunk':
```

My code:

```
tp1 = pd.read_csv('C:\test\\test.csv',chunksize=50,iterator=True)


a = 0

f = open(path2%str(a),'ab+')
last_file = path2%str(a)


for chunk in tp1:

    if int(os.stat(last_file).st_size) < 50:

        chunk.drop_duplicates(inplace=False,subset='kol2')
        chunk.to_csv(last_file,mode='ab+')

    else:

        a += 1
        last_file = path2%str(a)

        chunk.drop_duplicates(inplace=False,subset='kol2')
        chunk.to_csv(last_file,mode='ab+')
```

I have no idea what's going on.

Thank's for replies!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

#### Initialize `'test.csv'`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((1, 0), (200, 2)), columns=list('ab'))
df.insert(0, 'label', np.random.choice(list('ABCDE'), 200))

df.to_csv('test.csv', index=None)
```

#### Process for 1 file

```
# Initialize 'output.csv' with just the header
df.iloc[:0].to_csv('output.csv', index=None)

# wrap key word args together for cleanliness
output_kwds = dict(index=None, mode='a', header=None)

chunker = pd.read_csv('test.csv', chunksize=10, iterator=True)

for chunk in chunker:
    chunk.drop_duplicates(subset='label').to_csv('output.csv', **output_kwds)
```

#### Validation

```
df_ = pd.read_csv('output.csv')

df_.label.describe()

count     90
unique     5
top        D
freq      20
Name: label, dtype: object
```

#### Process for separate files

```
# wrap key word args together for cleanliness
output_kwds = dict(index=None, mode='a')

chunker = pd.read_csv('test.csv', chunksize=10, iterator=True)

for i, chunk in enumerate(chunker):
    chunk.drop_duplicates(subset='label').to_csv('output%s.csv' % i, **output_kwds)
```